# Vulnarable site jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'd like to know what to do if I find a high traffic site that is vulnerable to JS/SQL injection? I contacted the owner but it doesn't seem they care.

I can easily submit the `<script>` in their discussion forums and trigger the execution. Is there a fair best practices on how to direct the website owner to protect themselves?

In worst scenario, should I hack their site and force them this way to correct it?

Comment: [Somewhat applicable](https://xkcd.com/386/) ... Other than that, opinions on this will vary widely ... I know quite a few sites that are not secure, but can't really be arsed to do anything other than send an email... sometimes this helps, usually not ...

Comment: Hacking is prohibited, except if you like police. Contact webmaster@thesite.com or its hosting company on its abuse email address... Maybe they will forward you discover to the website owner but anyone can force him to fix this issue.

Comment: You seem to have good intentions, and if you've already informed the site's owner, there's not a lot else you can do. You could spread the word on social media to inform the users as well, but it's probably best to move on to other things.

Comment: Problem with these things is that it costs MONEY. And this is something not many companies have or want to invest... So besides spamming them that their website has 'huge' security issues, there is nothing else you can do..

Comment: Most sites don't run in-house forum software.  If it's a package, try submitting the bug to the vendor